# User Control styles

Tags: asp.net, css, user-controls

I have this .ascx page that contains this code :

```
<%=Morning%>
  <br />
<%=Sunrise%>
  <br />
<%=afternoon%>
```

in the code behind .ascx.cs

```
XmlNodeList _morning= _doc.GetElementsByTagName("morning");
  morning= "morning" + _morning[0].InnerText.ToString();

XmlNodeList _sunrise = _doc.GetElementsByTagName("sunrise");
  Sunrise = "Sunrise" + _sunrise[0].InnerText.ToString();
```

so the result would look like :

```
morning  12:00 PM
Sunrise  5:00 AM
```

What I want to do is to add styles on each element; I need to have `morning` with one style and `12:00 PM` with a different one.  How do I do it using CSS? I mean, how could I specify to each have their own class?

Comment: Sally, under what conditions do you want the style to change? For example, are you expecting the class on the element to change when a certain time has passed, on page load, or not at all?

Comment: I helped you edit this question to make it a little cleaner. I hope you can learn from this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`morning = "<span style='color: Red;'>morning</span><span style='color: Yellow;'>" + _morning[0].InnerText.ToString() + "</span>";`

This will alter the colour of `morning` to Red and the colour of `time` to Yellow.  However, this is inline styles and you could use a class instead.

`morning = "<span class='morning'>morning</span><span class='time'>" + _morning[0].InnerText.ToString() + "</span">";`

and in your css file:

```
.morning
{
    color: Red;
}

.time
{
    color: Yellow;
}
```